# Postgres JSONB type query from JPA

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jsonb

I have a table called questionnaire and it contains a column with jsonb type which is also named questionnaire. I want to do below query in using JPA.

JSON -

```
{"guid": "9c36adc1-7fb5-4d5b-83b4-90356a46061a", "name": "Angela Barton", "tags": ["enim", "aliquip", "qui"], "address": "178 Howard Place, Gulf, Washington, 702", "company": "Magnafone", "latitude": 19.793713, "is_active": true, "longitude": 86.513373, "registered": "2009-11-07T08:53:22 +08:00"}
```

Quey

```
SELECT * FROM questionnaire WHERE questionnaire @>'{"company": "Magnafone"}';
```

JPA Repository code

```
@Repository
public interface QuestionnaireRepository extends JpaRepository<Questionnaire, Long> {


    @Query("select u from Questionnaire u where u.questionnaire @> = ?1")
    List<Questionnaire> findFromQuestionnaireQuery(String json);
}
```

since there is @ in the Query it throws a error in JPA. How to resolve this

Comment: can you also add the stack trace of the error that you receive ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to enable `nativeQuery = true`, it is going to solve the problem.

```
  @Query(value = "select * from Questionnaire u where u.questionnaire @> = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Questionnaire> findFromQuestionnaireQuery(String json);
```

Comment: I used you answer but didn't work below error is occurring.

Comment: can you update the question with stack trace of the problem ?